# How do you call Robolectric's ShadowWifiManager.setScanResults()?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

During testing, I need to make the `WifiManager.getScanResults()` method return a non-empty list. I'm using Robolectric. I found the `ShadowWifiManager` has a `setScanResults()` method, that takes a list of `ScanResult` objects -- but they don't have a public constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that **Robolectric** has a shadow of `ScanResult`, also, which has a `newInstance` method. It can be used like this:

```
shadowOf(((WifiManager)controller.get().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))).setScanResults(Collections.singletonList(ShadowScanResult.newInstance("Foo", "Bar", "", 1, 2)));
```

or, more verbosely:

`final int level = 5;
final int frequency = 100;
final ScanResult scanResult = ShadowScanResult.newInstance(
    "A fake SSID", "A fake BSSID", "Some capabilities", level, frequency);
final Context context = controller.get();
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
shadowOf(wifiManager).setScanResults(Collections.singletonList(scanResult));`